# The best way to insert new record with ID(PK) in other fields with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I know django row queries - great.
But, is it possible make it in Django ORM?

For example for SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table (extra_ident) VALUES (id);
```

Comment: You can use `MyModel.objects.create(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you don't need to use "insert" to create new entries, you simply use `Table.objects.create(extra_ident=id)` to insert into table.

Comment: Like this?

`t = Table(extra_ident=id)
t.save()`
I can't insert record with new generated id(pk) in extra_ident column.

Comment: Because the pk(id) is generated by django upon an object is created, and before you call save() or create() to create an object it doesn't exist yet. I honestly don't know why you want an `extra_ident` storing id(pk). If you need to use it, you can create an object then do `object.id`, it will give you the automatic id generated by django.

Comment: Thanks. Nice that you aksing why i need extra identtyficator.
It was example. I need it for inserting and creating parents path in one query:
http://monkeyandcrow.com/blog/hierarchies_with_postgres/
Maby i will use row query.